# Can't install old versions with pip anymore

Tags: python, pip

I'n using pip 1.5.1 which worked fine up until today.

Now, I'm trying to install a requirements.txt in a fresh virtualenv, and for many packages it can no longer find specific old version for most packages.

```
$ pip install django-endless-pagination==1.1 
Downloading/unpacking django-endless-pagination==1.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-endless-pagination==1.1 (from versions: 2.0)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-endless-pagination==1.1
```

What do I need to do to get this to work again? Upgrading my app to use all the latest versions of all its packages is out of the question.

Update:
This works fine in pip 1.4.1.  It's the newer version of pip that's causing it to fail.

Comment: Try `--allow-external` as the message suggests.

Comment: Further discussion of this issue here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1423

Comment: --allow-external fails with a different error saying you need to add --allow-unverified, which also fails with a message 'You must give at least one requirement to install'

Answer (score 4):

From [PIP 1.5 changelog](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/news.html#id3):

> **BACKWARD INCOMPATIBLE**
>
> pip no longer will scrape insecure external urls by default nor will it install externally hosted files by
>   default. Users may opt into installing externally hosted or insecure
>   files or urls using `--allow-external PROJECT` and `--allow-unverified
>   PROJECT`

So in this case following ought to work the same way as old PIP:

```
pip install django-endless-pagination==1.1 \
--allow-all-external --allow-unverified django-endless-pagination
```

(There is [no `--allow-all-unverified`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1268), each unverified project name must be specified)

In case of using `requirements.txt`, it should be specified like this:

```
--allow-external django-endless-pagination
--allow-unverified django-endless-pagination

django-endless-pagination==1.1
```

Comment: This still fails with a message saying to add --allow-unverified, and adding that also fails

Comment: So this needs to be added for each and every package in requirements.txt now?  Seems nuts that they have to be listed three times.

Comment: @LeeSemel: for external install I guess `--allow-all-external` in `requirements.txt` would do also. As for unverified, there is no working around that. Verified packages are these, which have their checksum stored in PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use the URL of the appropriate zip file as input to [pip install](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install)::

```
pip install https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination/archive/v1.1.zip
```

Of course, not every package will have such a URL available, but most do.

I've occasionally used this to install the latest-greatest master, since in some cases the cheeseshop didn't have Python 3 ready packages yet.

Answer (score -1):

Because the version on PyPI is 2.0 and pip now tries to honor the fact that maintainer wants you to use given version.